# Re-opening GUI doesn't show saved data

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I need help.
When I reopen GUI, it doesn't shows what has been saved into the file, which was serialization. The file is saving successful, but when I close and reopen and run the application it doesn't show on JList, what was saved into this file.

```
    try
    {
        FileInputStream jos = new FileInputStream("jokam.ser");
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(jos);
        ObjectInputStream hehe = new ObjectInputStream(gis);
        v1= (Vector<Vector>)hehe.readObject();


        Vpredmeti.addAll((Collection<? extends Predmet>)v1.get(0));
        Vvlak.addAll((Collection<? extends Vlak>)v1.get(1));


        jos.close();
        hehe.close(); 
        gis.close();

        v1.addAll(0, v1);

       for(Predmet pr : predmetAR){
           System.out.println(pr);

       }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

}
```

}

These Vectors are before try code.

```
   Vector <Predmet> Vpredmeti = new Vector (predmetAR);
   Vector <Vlak> Vvlak= new Vector();
   Vector <Vector> v1 = new Vector<>();
```

**This is where I add to JList.**

```
   private void DodajPredmetMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   // DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
    String praznoPolje=ImePredmeta.getText();
    String drugoPraznoPolje=ZnacilnostPredmeta.getText();
    int tretjoPraznoPolje = (int)ComboBoxZabojnika.getSelectedIndex();
    Predmet novPredmet = new Predmet();
    novPredmet.ime = ImePredmeta.getText();
    novPredmet.znacilnosti = drugoPraznoPolje;
    novPredmet.tipZabojnika=tretjoPraznoPolje;
    //list.addElement(novPredmet);

    predmetAR.add(novPredmet);
```

**Save code**

```
  Vector<Predmet> Vpredmet = new Vector<>(predmetAR);
  Vector<Vlak> Vvlak = new Vector<>(vlakAR);
  Vector<Vector> v = new Vector<>();
  v.add(0,Vpredmet);
  v.add(1,Vvlak);



    try
   {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("jokam.ser");
       GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(gos);
       oos.writeObject(v);
       gos.close();
       fos.close();
       oos.close();


   }        
   catch(Exception e)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear at what time you are saving and what time you are loading the data. It's also difficult to understand since the variable numbers don't seem to be in english. Additionally, some variable names, including the Vectors, use capitol letters which is against commonly accepted style guides.

Comment: You should probably print stack traces in your catch clause; the answer might be an exception is being thrown and you never see it.

Comment: About saving, it's all good. The file is created, so I think, it's something here, when I open again the application. I will try with print stack traces.

Comment: Can you post the save code? The order you have the input stream closures seems off; Closing the lowes-level stream should be all you need to do; You should also close the streams in a finally block. In your example, if something goes wrong when reading the objects, the FileInputStream would remain open. You can use try with resource block as well. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I did. I edited the whole post now.

Comment: You still don't have the stack trace printing in the catch blocks; did you see any exceptions?

Comment: Yes I did it. And first one throwed me, an Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream - something like that. And second was, when I've closed the GUI, NotSerializableException.

Comment: You should try simplifying the code; it probably won't fix the problem but it will make it easier to read; instead of reading and writing 3 things, do just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Those exceptions you noted are almost definitely problems where a stream was closed early, either on the write part or the read part. It's also indicative of a layering problem with the streams, but I don't see that here.

To first step in solving these problems is making sure all the data is written before the stream is closed, and in the proper order. I usually `flush()` the highest level stream before closing it or underlying parts. `flush()` the highest level `OutputStream` (here, the `ObjectOutputStream`), and it will flush all the underlying streams (here the `GZIPOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream`). Technically `close()` also `flush()`es the stream so this may not be necessary.

Also, make sure to `close()` streams in the correct order. Same as `flush()`, close the higher level stream and the underlying streams get `close()`d (and `flush()`ed) automatically.

The code you already have `close()`es the `GZIPOutputStream` first, which precludes the closing bits of the `ObjectOutputStream`. Later, the `ObjectOutputStream` is `close()`d which will try to write those bits but the underlying stream has already been closed so, so an `IOException` is thrown.

When writing, I suggest trying just:

```
objectOutputStream.close();
```

As for the reading, just this should be good:

```
objectInputStream.close()
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you should `close()` in a `finally` block so that any `Exception` thrown in the `try` block still results in the `close()` being called. Be aware that `close()` can also throw an `Exception` ;)

To investigate this on your own, I suggest looking into the source code of all these streams to see what's happening inside. The JDK includes an optional `jdk/lib/src.zip`, which most IDE's will let you jump into. Try 'go to definition' on your `objectOutputStream.close()` and you should see the source code.